# How to save due date for each month or quarter of loan payment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

PaymentFrequency can be:

```
1 = Monthly
2 = Quarterly
3 = Yearly
```

One `LoanPayment` has many `LoanPaymentDetail`.

I want to use `PaymentCount`, `PaymentFrequency` and `DueDate` in `LoanPayment` to get the `DueDate` in `LoanPaymentDetail`.

For instance, when `PaymentMentCount = 4, PaymentFrequency = 1` (Monthly) and `DueDate = 29-01-2022`, it should add `DueDate` for 4 months, if that particular is not up to 29, it uses the closest date (28).

It does similar thing, if Quarterly and Yearly are selected.

This is what I have done so far.

```
public async Task<LoanPayment. AddLoanPayment(LoanPaymentCreateDto loanPaymentCreateDto)
{
    var mapper = new EntityMapper();
    var loanPaymentDetail = new LoanPaymentDetail();
    var loanPayment = mapper.FromLoanPaymentDtoToPayment(loanPaymentCreateDto);
    wait _unitOfWork.LoanPaymentRepository.Insert(loanPayment);
     // This saves loan Payment
    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Now to loop LoanPaymentDetail
    for (int i = 1, i <= (byte)loanPayment.PaymentFrequency)
    {
        loanPaymentDetail.LoanPaymentId = loanPayment.Id;
        loanPaymentDetail.DueDate = ???
        loanPaymentDetail.AmountPayable = loanPayment.Amount / AmountPayable.PaymentCount;
        wait _unitOfWork.LoanPaymentDetailRepository.Insert(loanPaymentDetail);
        // This saves loan Payment Detail
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return loanPayment;
}
```

How do I achieve my goal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What solutions you have been tried?

Comment: Can you explain the business logic of preserving the maturity date of loan payments? I'm not clear.